# oAuth in Background without intervation to end user

Tags: android, angularjs, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am newbie in oAuth 2.0. I have scenario in which there are 2 platform first is client side angular code and another one server side Node(Express) code. I want to implement oAuth 2.0 in background. The server application will communicate to google auth(Server will provide auth values) and without populating pop-up to end user i.e. to client app it will get authentication token. Then from angular app i want to call youtube api to access private channel video of user which token i received from server.
I have read this articles https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app

https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/?hl=en_US#creating-server-api-keys

So my question is this possible. As server app is different and client app will be different.

Comment: doesn't make sense. How can server communicate user credentials to google auth without user providing them? The whole point of signing in through google is user doesn't have to expose those credentials

Comment: The credential will reside on server side. It will be hard-coded. If i want to show some private channel video in my app using YouTube API.

Comment: but you only store the token provided back by google after user accepts your app access

Comment: @charlietfl I don't want to show app access pop-up in the browser. It will be handle in background.

Comment: then it sounds like what you are trying to do can't be done if user never approves your app through google

Answer (score 0):

Google has a way to do cross-client identity, so that all the client apps are grouped as a single project then when the user authenticates and gives permission for one of the clients to access their Google data, then this is applied to all of the clients, so it wont ask for the same permission again from another client.

See [Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth) about this. Basically you need to group the clients (that is, your Angular client and your node server) into one project in the Google API Console.